# Python. Convert datetime object to string with timezone included

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a date time object:

```
datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 13, 11, 8, 44, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

I need to convert this object to string like this

```
"2018-03-13 16:38:44+05:30"
```

Already tried:
1)
    obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%Z')

It gives `'2018-03-13 11:08:44UTC'` not `"2018-03-13 16:38:44+05:30"`

2) obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')

It gives `"2018-03-13 16:38:44+0530"` not `"2018-03-13 16:38:44+05:30"`

How can this be done????

Comment: Look at `datetime.datetime.strftime`

Comment: tired it, not working for time zone. It "%Z" just give the time zone "UIC" but not the exact difference

Comment: obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%Z') gives '2018-03-13 11:08:44UTC'

Comment: Try with `%z` (z in lower case)

Comment: @bro-grammer- start_t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z') gives '2018-03-01 00:00:00+0553' but I need ''2018-03-01 00:00:00+05:53''

Comment: Then take that string, slice it, and add a colon at the end

Comment: There is no strftime argument that would do exactly that. You need to add one line of code to insert the colon into your string. As the effort is not excessive and takes less time than commenting stackoverflow posts, it would probably be worth considering.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use the method `datetime.astimezone()` with or without arguments. It formats the output exactly as you expect, as shown in this example:

```
import datetime
import pytz

obj = datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 13, 11, 8, 44, tzinfo=pytz.utc)

print(obj.astimezone())                                 # date/time with system local timezone
print(obj.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Asia/Calcutta')))   # date/time in Calcutta: 2018-03-13 16:38:44+05:30 (your expected output)
```